# What is the name of the "Things are more visible once you learn about them" phenomenon?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, terminology, language

(Excuse the horrible title of this question. I just can't find the proper (?) words. Please edit as pleased.)

It happens many times to me that when I learn about something (e.g. a word, a concept, etc), I suddenly start to see it in many places. This is not due to a change in external circumstances but to "the way you look at things".

For example, I recently learned the word "oftentimes". I was not aware it existed before. And yet, I suddenly started to see it in many places, so that it caughts my attention. Naturally, people did not suddenly started to use this word, so this was clearly a change in my **perception**, due to "conceptual learning".

My question is, **is there a word for this psychological phenomenon?** I hardly find the proper words to search for this, so my efforts at the moment have been pointless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scenario you describe is sometimes called the [Baader-Meinhof Phenomenon](https://www.damninteresting.com/the-baader-meinhof-phenomenon/).

> Baader-Meinhof is the phenomenon where one stumbles upon some obscure
>   piece of information—often an unfamiliar word or name—and soon
>   afterwards encounters the same subject again, often repeatedly.

The more scientifically accepted name for this [cognitive bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases) seems to be **'frequency illusion'**.

> The illusion in which a word, a name, or other thing that has recently
>   come to one's attention suddenly seems to appear with improbable
>   frequency shortly afterwards[.]

As to why it occurs, [this article](http://science.howstuffworks.com/life/inside-the-mind/human-brain/baader-meinhof-phenomenon.htm) seems to state a combination of selective attention (or [attentional control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attentional_control)) and [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias):

> One, your brain seems to be excited by the fact that you've learned
>   something new, and selective attention occurs. Your brain
>   subconsciously thinks, "Hey, that's awesome! I'm going to look for
>   that thing without actually thinking about it." So now that you're
>   looking for it, you find it. To make it all the more powerful,
>   confirmation bias occurs after seeing it even once or twice. In other
>   words, you start agreeing with yourself that, yup, you're definitely
>   seeing it more